# How to map JSON object to Spring Object

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

How to map JSON object to Spring Object... I have AJAX, posting a JSON object to my Spring Controller but how do I make Spring turn that JSON into a Object in java

Java Code:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/employee")
    public ModelAndView addEmployee(@RequestBody String body) {

        System.out.println("in post: " + body);
        Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(body));


        System.out.println("source: " + source.toString());
        //
        // how do I turn the JSON String into a Java Object?
        //
        return new ModelAndView(XML_VIEW_NAME, "object", body);
    }
```

JavaSript/html code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>This is a project to show how to use RESTful</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">var contexPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";</script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjaxPost() {  


    var queryString = $('#htmlform').serialize();

    alert("doAjaxPost Called :" + queryString +":");

       $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : 'json',
            type : "POST",
            url : contexPath + "/service/employee",
            data : queryString, //json serialization (like array.serializeArray() etc)

            success : function(data) {
                alert("Thanks for submitting.  \n\n" + response.result);
               // response
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {
                   alert('Error: ' + e); 
            }
        });
    }  
</script>

<H1>Add Employee</H1>

<p>
<form name="htmlform" id="htmlform">
<table border=1>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr></thead>

    <tr>
        <td><input  type="text" name="ID" maxlength="5" size="3"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="Name" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="Email" maxlength="10" size="10"></td>
    </tr>

</table>
<input type="button" value="Save Employee" onclick="doAjaxPost();" />
<p>
<p>
</form>
[<a href="http://localhost:8080/RESTful/service/employees">List all Employees</a> | <a href="add.jsp">Employee Form Test</a>]


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to:

- send JSON object, not JSON String
- included Jackson on your classpath

Then you can add  `@RequestBody Employee employee` at the controller's method signature.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using Spring 3.0+. Take a look at Spring Source blog post on [JSON simplifications](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/). It seems that you're half way there already.

Answer (score 0):

**Use JSON mapping library** such as [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Your code would look approximately as :

```
Employee e;
try {
    e = objectMapper.readValue(body, Employee .class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't parse json into a employee", e);
}
```

If you using Spring 3 or higher, there is even simpler way to do it:
http://blog.springsource.org/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/